# How can i parse this json string using php?

Tags: php, json

Here is my json string:

```
{
"routes": [
    {
        "bounds": {
            "northeast": {
                "lat": 41.9291739,
                "lng": 23.7293099
            },
            "southwest": {
                "lat": 37.9103506,
                "lng": 12.4822041
            }
        },
        "copyrights": "Map data,google",
        "legs": [
            {
                "distance": {
                    "text": "1,250 km",
                    "value": 1249958
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

i want to get routes->legs->distance->value
im using this code unsuccessfully:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('./test.txt'));
$distance = $json->routes[0]->legs[0]->distance->value;
var_dump($distance);
```

any ideas?

Comment: That looks correct and should [work](http://3v4l.org/Ab1I9). What error do you get (if any)?

Comment: im getting: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: But json_decode() only works with php 5.2 or greater.  What is your php version?   phpinfo();

Comment: it's on wamp and php version is 5.4.2

Comment: @mike_x_: What does `var_dump( file_exists('test.txt') );` output?

Comment: try json_decode with true parameter

Comment: $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('./test.txt'), TRUE);
now $json is an Array and $distance = $json['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['distance']['value']; Does it work ?

Comment: @ElSinus: It's not different and the output would be the same. I think the problem is with `file_get_contents()` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're having problems reading your file, the code below works.

Does the file exist in the same dir?
Does your file has the json content?
Maybe you don't have permission on the file.

```
<?php

$json=json_decode('{
"routes": [
    {
        "bounds": {
            "northeast": {
                "lat": 41.9291739,
                "lng": 23.7293099
            },
            "southwest": {
                "lat": 37.9103506,
                "lng": 12.4822041
            }
        },
        "copyrights": "Map data,google",
        "legs": [
            {
                "distance": {
                    "text": "1,250 km",
                    "value": 1249958
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
}');

$distance = $json->routes[0]->legs[0]->distance->value;
var_dump($distance);
```

Comment: if i add it as string it works for me too... i also changed encoding but no luck...